# How to test a method inside of my unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following method:

```
public void transactionOfSupplierOrder() {
        List<NavSuppliersOrder> navList = navRepo.findAll();
        try {
                SuppliersOrder nut = null;
                for (NavSuppliersOrder nav : navList) {
                    SuppliersOrderLog log = createLog();
                    nut = convert(nav);
                    nut = saveRecord(nav, log, nut);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

I am trying to make a unit test like:

```
 @Test
    public void canDoTransactionOfSupplierOrder(){
        //given
        NavSuppliersOrder navSuppliersOrder = new NavSuppliersOrder();
        List<NavSuppliersOrder> navList = new ArrayList<>();
        navList.add(navSuppliersOrder);

        //when
        Mockito.doReturn(navList).when(navRepo).findAll();
        suppliersOrderService.transactionOfSupplierOrder();

        //then
        //Mockito.verify(suppliersOrderService).createLog();
    }
```

So basically I am trying to find a way to get to saveRecord() method (which is in the same class as the transactionOfSupplierOrder() method) and test it from this unit test. Is that even possible and if it is does my test than count as a unit or a integration test? In case if it isn't possible is my only testing option to verify if saveRecord() was just called and than test the saveRecord() method as a separate unit test?

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that you want to unit test the `saveRecord()` method? If it is the case I would verify if it was called and test the `saveRecord()` method in a separate unit test. Otherwise you would be testing two different things: 1. the transaction and 2. the saving.

Comment: You understood it correctly, thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with testing two methods in one unit test as long as they have the same concern. In this case there are two different concerns: the transaction (which does logging, converting and saving) and saving. If there is a bug it is easier to determine the root cause if you have separate unit tests.